Why can't Windbg's SOS extension give me Syncblock data?
I'm using the Windbg GUI to try to troubleshoot an error in a WPF application, which is self-contained with dotnet SDK 8.0.108
If I run "!syncblk", I get this error message:

Error requesting SyncBlk data

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this error message? Why can't it get the syncblk data?
As requested, I've created a minimum reproducible example here
Steps to reproduce:

Clone that repo
Run the console project - it will create a dump file on the desktop
Run the wpf project, and click the button - it will create a second dump file on the desktop
Open the first dump file (from the console project), and type "!syncblk" command - it should work
Open the second dump file (from the wpf project), and type "!syncblk" command - it should give the error message "Error requesting SyncBlk data".

I'll be interested to hear if anyone else can verify this same repro, or if it's specific to my machine somehow.
I'm using WinDbg 1.2407.24003.0, with the default SOS extension.

Exactly which SOS Extension did you download and install?

I meant that SOS is the WinDBG extension which has the syncblk command. I'll try to edit the title to be more clear.

Well, yes - but there are multiple versions and editions of the SOS WinDbg extnesion (e.g. for .NET Framework 1,x, 2.x, 4.x, .NET Core 2.x, etc).

Please provide a [mre]. Can you reproduce that with a simple console app? If so, please provide the code. How do you debug it exactly? Please provide your debugging session log. E.g. the command will not work at the initial breakpoint, because .NET has not been loaded yet.

Thanks for providing the MRE. That was very useful to find the source of the issue.

You are creating the crash dump yourself using DiagnosticsClient.
In your code you have
var dumpType = DumpType.Normal;
// var dumpType = DumpType.WithHeap;

SyncBlocks are stored along with the objects on the heap. Besides the object data, there's also the method table (MT) in front of the object and the syncblock in front of the method table. As explained in a MS article.
In order to analyze sync blocks, you need the heap, because the information is only there. The solution is in the commented line of code: store the crash dump with heap information.
Why DumpType.WithHeap fails with HRESULT 0x80004005 (E_FAIL) - I have no idea. I switched to DumpType.Full and could successfully run !syncblk:
0:000> !syncblk
Index         SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info          SyncBlock Owner
-----------------------------
Total           80
CCW             5
RCW             10
ComClassFactory 0
Free            0


Thankyou! The only thing that doesn't really explain is why !syncblk does work on a normal dump in the console app, but perhaps it's because there is nothing on the heap in that simple console app?

@dbruning: you are right. I didn't have a look into the console application. In .NET there's a lot on the heap, even in a simple hello world console application.
